# No Data in Sent Items when sending email using Laravel and IBM Notes

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, lotus-notes

Good day.

I am currently using Laravel 5.3 Mailer and an IBM notes email account.

I was able to successfully sent emails but when I looked at the sent items of the email that I used for sending, there was none.

I am currently using this configuration in .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=ourhostip
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=myaccount
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

In my controller I am using this code.

```
$data = "Testing Data";
$email = "email";
$name = "Name";
Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['data' => $data], function ($mail) use ($name,$email) {
    $mail->from('fromemail', 'AI');
    $mail->to($email, $name)->subject('Testing Email!');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with IBM Notes rather than Laravel. See if there are any settings in Notes that could enable storing of sent messages.

Comment: @NirajShah I tried using IBM Notes in emailing and it records my sent emails. On the other hand, when I use my IBM account for sending email in Laravel there is no trace of my sent emails.

Comment: The issue would be related to sending emails outside of IBM Notes. Have you tried to send an email using a different email client but using the same SMTP settings as used in Laravel? Does it show in the Sent folder?

Comment: Yes @NirajShah. I also tried using my personal account in gmail and the problem still persists.

Comment: I don't mean sending to a different email, I mean actually using a different email client (e.g. outlook, thunderbird, spark etc) to send a mail using the SMTP details of IBM Note. The point of this test is to see if an email sent outside of Laravel also causes this issue. If it does, it means the issue isn't Laravel related!

Comment: I tried sending email in IBM notes using the credentials that I used in my Laravel application. It records a sent items but when I used Laravel Mailer there is none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the way SMTP works. When you use Outlook,Thunderbird, etc. to write an email via SMTP and your Notes/Domino Account you can see the E-Mail in your Notes Sent Folder only if you configure an IMAP Connection too.

I'm afraid this is not posible in Laravel.

If you want to have the E-Mail in your IBM Notes Inbox you can send the mail with BCC to your own address (and move it with a mail rule to a folder).

Comment: Not strictly true, and it's dependent on the email provider you use. I use Zoho emails in Laravel with no IMAP configured, and Zoho currently shows the messages sent using Laravel in the Sent folder when using the web email client.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will try it asap. I will also coordinate with our technical support for any configuration regarding your answer. Will get back to you in a while. Thanks!

Comment: I just used your 2nd suggestion to simply not over complicate things and it works! Using BCC is my emails can also be a basis of the sent items. I just create a mail rule function so that I can see all the emails sent using Laravel. It is also beneficial when it comes to separating sent emails using IBM Notes and using my Laravel App. Hope that my question and your answer could contribute more on this community. Thanks! :)